# Как объеденить php?

Tags: php

```
<img src="<?php echo IMAGE_SMALL_PATH ?> <?php echo $row['small']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['alt']; ?>" />
```

в пути до изображения которое хранится в define IMAGE_SMALL_PATH а само изображение из базы - как это объеденить ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img src="<?= IMAGE_SMALL_PATH . $row['small'] ?>" alt="<?= $row['alt']; ?>" />
```

Comment: и всё ?больше ни чего не нужно ?

Comment: Если вы хотите объединить константу IMAGE_SMALL_PATH и переменную $row['small'], то больше ничего не нужно. Связывание идет через точку.

Comment: я может давно и не писал на php, но в чем проблема писать так `<?=$row['small'];?>` ?) Зачем каждый раз писать `<?php echo .. ?>`?

Comment: обалдеть - спасибо - лучший ответ - но к сожалению можно выбрать только через 11 минут

Comment: <img src="<?=echo IMAGE_SMALL_PATH . $row['small']; ?>" alt="<?=echo $row['alt']; ?>" />  вот так ?

Comment: Нет. Поправил пост

Comment: @LenovoID нет, `<?=IMAGE_SMALL_PATH . $row['small']; ?>`.  <?= это уже `<?php echo`. Сокращение такое

Comment: Просто все поголовно пишут `<?php echo ` я думал может случилось чего))

Comment: echo уже не надо писать ?

Comment: @LenovoID я же пояснил что `<?=` это уже `<?php echo`

Comment: Это уже синтаксический сахар) Например я предпочитаю через echo, нежели сокращенный вариант. В IDE например заметнее и приятнее)

Comment: т.е <?php echo ?> = <?= > это одно и тоже ?

Comment: Это одно и тоже)  --- http://s017.radikal.ru/i422/1604/b5/5bffaef62079.png

Comment: Urmuz Tagizade спасибо - ЛО